# Code block display bug?

Tags: support, code-formatting

I noticed that [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36111133/14165730) used triple backticks in the markdown, but the rendered output looks strange to me. Is there a bug somewhere?

[image]

Comment: It looks fine if you click on edit and see the preview

Comment: needs an empty line at the start of the code fence